# How to run jUnit tests on class library with no config classes?

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit, class-library, jacoco-maven-plugin

I have a solution which consists of 3 projects, 2 that use the last project as a class library (the entities, repositories, services, exceptions and other common code are all in this library).  I am using Jacoco on the 2 other projects that depend on the class library to get an idea of how many scenarios i need to test.

Testing on the 2 child projects is simple, see this for example :

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = {MDHIS_WebClient.class, ApplicationConfiguration.class, HibernateConfiguration.class}, 
webEnvironment = WebEnvironment.DEFINED_PORT)
public class UserServiceTest
{
    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @Test
    public void checkIfAdminUserExists()
    {
        assertNotNull(userService.findByUserId("admin"));
    }
}
```

However, the report Jacoco outputs only contains results for this project, not the class library that it depends on.  I cannot find a way to build this kind of tests in the class library since it's just that, a library.  It has no context for JUnit to hook into since it does nothing on its own.  Still, there are hundreds of methods in that class library that i want to test and I cannot figure out how to expose them to Jacoco.  I can write JUnit tests in one of the child projects that test features in the class library, in fact my example above is exactly such test, but Jacoco does not produce any results for it since it's included in the project with a Maven dependency.

How could i go about obtaining results for this shared library in one of the dependent projects or how can i create JUnit tests in the class library that are context-independant?

Thanks!